# how to save or retrieve data from mysql when we cannot open it anymore?

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to save or retrieve data from my co-workers computer. Her MySQL instance does not work anymore (cannot figure out the reasons). I would like to know if there is a way to save all the data from the databases present in her computer.

Any suggestions on how to save the data, and maybe re-install MySQL again?

Comment: this is the error message: "Your connection attemp failed for user 'root' from your host to server at 127.0.0.1:3306: can't connect to Mysql server on '127.0.0.1' (10061).

Comment: You should look at past questions and accept answers if they suit your needs.

Comment: As for the error messages, I was actually asking what error messages you're seeing for the MySQL server. Client error messages aren't helpful here.

Comment: You accept answers on your old questions by clicking the tick mark under the vote score of the answer. For errors, try checking the [error log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/error-log.html). It might be a simple error to solve and you don't have to recover the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy the tables to another computer with a working MySQL instance, as long as the floating point format is the same on both computers ([see this page for reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/copying-databases.html), covered in the first paragraph).

As long as you copy the .frm, .myd and .myi files somewhere safe, you can also try reinstalling MySQL and see if that works for you.

Comment: do you mean that by copying those files and bringing them on another computer, we will be able to restore the entire database?

Comment: Yes, you can bring those files to another computer.  Put them into an empty database, and then you can just query them straight away.  MyISAM is very resilient when it comes to loading up data files like that.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, errors may be recoverable. If you do not have ability to recover from errors, you can try to make a plain copy of MySQL data. BUT! If tables used InnoDB engine, that will  be not so easy and chance of recovery will be not so big.